# Seaborn bar plot by dataframe order

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Let's say I want a barplot for sale quantities per week, over Q4 2020 and Q1 2021. At some point, week numbers will reset to 1, which will not represent the actual order of the data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Year": [2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021],
        "Week": [50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3],
        "Qty": [173, 29, 16, 46, 39, 82],
    }
)
```

So, I want my barplot x axis to be ordered like my data frame: 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3

But if I do this:

```py
sns.barplot(x='Week', y='Qty', data=df)
```

I get that:

[image]

The data is ordered by ascending value of the x axis (week number), not according to the order of my dataframe.

I thought the the `order` parameter was precisely what I was looking for and could be used to order the bars along the dataframe index:

```py
sns.barplot(x='Week', y='Qty', data=df, order=df.index)
```

But then, it only takes year 2021:

[image]

What do I need to do?

Comment: `order=df['Week']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try convert `Week` column to string type

```py
sns.barplot(x=df['Week'].astype(str), y=df['Qty'])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked, as well as `order=df['Week']` (I thought the latter would produce exactly what I was seeing, i.e. by ascending order of week number). Thank you both!